# Hierarchical grid containing user controls issue with unique IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a nested Kendo `Grid` which contains a `TabStrip` control which, in turn, contains multiple `kendoComboBox`s generated from initial `div` elements.

The grid is generated in Javascript:

```
$("#configAddGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridConfigDataSourceAdd,
        height: 550,
        detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#templateAdd").html()),
        detailInit: detailAddInit,
        navigatable: true,
        autoBind: false,
        editable: {
            mode: "incell"
        },
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: columnSchemaAdd
    });
```

`kendo-template` is defined below. The `TabStrip` is uniquely identified using an `ID` field of each row:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabStripAdd_#=ID#")
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
        .Items(items =>
        {
                items.Add().Text((string)ViewBag.ControlSetLots[0].LotNumber).Content(@<text>

                    <p>StandardComment: </p>
                    <div id='Lot1StandardCommentDropDownAdd_#=ID#' class='Lot1StandardCommentDropDownAdd'>    
                    </div> 
                    <p>Review Comment: </p>
                    <div id='Lot1ReviewCommentDropDownAdd_#=ID#' class='Lot1ReviewCommentDropDownAdd'>        
                    </div>

                   </text>
                );
            }...
```

And my plan is to initialise each of the Kendo `ComboBox`s through the `detailAddInit` function i.e. once a request is sent to expand a row. The creation of the `ComboBox` will be based on the unique ID of the `div`.
However the `#=ID#` assigned to the `div` is empty when inspected with the Inspector Window (emptyID.png) even though it is appended to the `TabStrip` control.

```
function detailAddInit(e) {
    var closestCB = e.detailRow.find('.Lot1StandardCommentDropDownAdd');        

    createStandardCommentDropDown("#Lot1StandardCommentDropDownAdd");
    createReviewCommentDropDown("#Lot1ReviewCommentDropDownAdd");            
    kendo.bind(e.detailRow, e.data);
}
```

Is there a way I can append the same ID to the end of my `div` to make it unique?[image: Difference between TabStrip and Div IDs]

Additionally, if anyone can think of a better way to achieve the same outcome, please feel free to comment as I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to ensure that each ComboBox gets assigned with a unique ID.

1) Removed the `ID` assigned in the `cshtml`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabStripEdit_#=ID#")
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
        .Items(items =>
        {                
            items.Add().Text((string)ViewBag.ControlSetLots[0].LotNumber).Content(@<text>

                <p>Standard Comment: </p>
                <div class='Lot1StandardCommentDropDownEdit'>
                </div>
                <p>Review Comment: </p>
                <div class='Lot1ReviewCommentDropDownEdit'>
                </div>

                </text>
            );
        }
```

2) Modified the `detailAddInit(e)` function to assign a unique `div` ID using the current time that the nested `detailTemplate` is requested from the `Grid`:

```
function detailAddInit(e) {
    var time = new Date().getTime().toString();
    // find combo box associated with current row
    var closestSCCB = e.detailRow.find('.Lot1StandardCommentDropDownAdd');            
    // assign a unique ID to the div
    var SCID = 'Lot1StandardCommentDropDownAdd_' + time;
    closestSCCB.attr('id', SCID);
    var closestSCCB2 = e.detailRow.find('.Lot1StandardCommentDropDownAdd');            

    var closestRCCB = e.detailRow.find('.Lot1ReviewCommentDropDownAdd');
    var RCID = 'Lot1ReviewCommentDropDownAdd_' + time;
    closestRCCB.attr('id', RCID);
    var closestRCCB2 = e.detailRow.find('.Lot1ReviewCommentDropDownAdd');

    createStandardCommentDropDown(closestSCCB2[0]);
    createReviewCommentDropDown(closestRCCB2[0]);   
}
```

Although this is quite I niche scenario, I hope this can make someones day in the future!